# Write class attribute to specific part of spreadsheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have created a code that will write directly to an excel template [excel template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ecWV.png). My issue is that I am unable to create the right loop to make it happen. I know it's something that is just right in front of my face, but I can't put my finger on it. As you can see from excel template, I want to populate the sheet with min_row=2,max_row=9, min_col=2, max_col=len(servers)+1

The data that needs to be written to the sheet is in this format

```
import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass

#define class for each server
@dataclass
class Server:
    name: str
    region :str
    domain: str
    os_name: str
    ip: str
    os_version: str
    installed_date: str
    env: str
```

My code to write the code to excel is as such:

```
for server in servers:            
        for col in ws.iter_cols(min_col=2,max_col=len(servers)+1,max_row=9,min_row=2):
            for cell in col:
                #print(col)
                #print('\n')
                cell.value=server.name
                print(cell)
                cell.value=server.region
                cell.value=server.domain
```

where servers is the list of server entered by user. The code is writing the first server to the excel file for a number of times.

Can you please rectify the error?

Comment: You're writing the same data to the same cell repeatedly. Please provide a sample table of how you want the data to be stored.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. Yes, it is in the link <excel template.>

Comment: Use`zip(servers, ws.iter_cols(…)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openpyxl's `iter_cols` will iterate through range of min & max of rows & columns for each of the server.

So, it ideally overwrites the cell contents with the server details repeatedly since it's in a **for loop of servers**.

What you can do is

```
for col_ind, col in enumerate(ws.iter_cols(min_col=2,max_col=len(servers)+1,max_row=9,min_row=2)):
    for cell in col:         
        cell.value=servers[col_ind].name
        cell.value=servers[col_ind].region
        cell.value=servers[col_ind].domain
```

You can check [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html) for more cell properties

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But cell.col_idx will give you thecurrent column index and we are starting it off with 2. So it will be list index out of range. right?
I am thinking a for loop is needed for this but how do i implement it ? :/

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that! Either the `iter_cols` should write one row at a time or you need to enumerate the `ws.iter_cols` parameter. I'll update my answer.